# How can I detect when leaving a row in a bindingsource?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindingsource, updating

I have a datagridview showing baisc document data (Name, type), which the user navigates to access each document.
A richtext box shows the first page of each document as navigation occurs.
However, since there can be multiple pages per document, the pages are managed in a separate BindingSource so the user can "flip" through them and make changes.

If the user makes changes to either say the document name or to information on any of the pages, he has 2 choices for saving these, either via an Update button or via navigating to another document in the datagridview.

The button is fine because all binding sources are in a "static" state.

However, I'm having trouble with the second option since datagridview doesn't offer a "row changing" event. The "RowLeave" event isn't appropriate since the user may be in a row, but click over to the richtext box to edit a corresponding page which, of course fires the "RowLeave" event. I only want to capture an event when the user actually changes document.

I've tried the Documents BindingSource "CurrentChanged" and "PositionChanged" events but they both occur after the "Current" pointer has changed so I don't have the correct context for the update(s). I could have a global "CurrentPosition" variable which is used to regain context while I do the updates, but that seems inelegant. Being fairly new to this, I'm guessing that I've missed something so any help would be fantastic.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

hi try to use the bindingSource `CurrentItemChanged` function

example:

```
private void bindingSource1_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty) return; // or IsCurrentRowDirty
//Your code
}
```

i hope it will help :)

Comment: Hi spajce, I tried this event too, but it is also fired after the current "pointer" has changed. Remember I am really changing rows not just cells within a row. Any other suggestions would really help.